# Ubuntu Postgresql-9.3 Replication Database how to re-sync data in master

Tags: server, postgresql, database

In here, I have 2 server

1. Server for Master Database (postgresql-9.3.12)
2. Server for Slave Database (postgresql-9.3.10)

Some this time, often crashes in the slave database servers.
When this happens I have to reconfigure to synchronize the data in the  slave database servers to master database servers.

If the data on the master database servers is very large, it is very time consuming.

How I can re-sync data slave database servers to master database servers without reconfiguration again?

Tutorial I follow : [Binary Replication in 7 Steps](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Binary_Replication_Tutorial#Binary_Replication_in_7_Steps)

You help is invaluable for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I cannot comment yet - we run replication on 9.3 on several instances without any problems. And if there are some interruptions replica resynchronizes itself - presuming "archive_mod" on master is ON - https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Binary_Replication_Tutorial#Setting_Up_Archiving_On_The_Master

What "crashes" you have? Can you post error messages?